# With CSS3, can I create keyframes that make border pulse in and out?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an image with a border surrounding. I want to have the border fade in and out. Is this possible with opacity + webkit keyframes? Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? Play around in http://jsfiddle.net and see if you can come up with something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
@keyframes border-pulsate {
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1); }
    50%  { border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0); }
    100% { border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1); }
}

img {
    border: 20px solid cyan;
    animation: border-pulsate 2s infinite;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RYT8L/4/

---

Note that in the real world, you'll have to include all the vendor prefixes, or use [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/)'s excellent tool called [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) (which is what I'm using in that fiddle).

Comment: Do you mind creating a fiddle? This looks really interesting (haven't seen it before). I tried to get it to work, but nothing seemed to happen. http://jsfiddle.net/kVKp7/

Comment: @mrtsherman - Like I said: either add vendor prefixes, or use [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/). I even tried including it in your fiddle, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/kVKp7/1/

Comment: Thanks Joseph. And thanks even more for the reference to prefix-free!

Comment: @mrtsherman - Even though Lea claims that this does not violate progressive-enhancement/graceful-degradation theory, I think it does. So I use -prefix-free while developing, but run my CSS through [prefixer](http://prefixr.com/) before deploying.

Comment: @mrtsherman - Also, keep in mind that none of this will work in IE < 10

Answer (score 9):

Try this pulsating border:    [DEMO (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DBNxr/)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulseBorder {
  from {
    border: solid 1px #f00;
  }
  to {
    border: solid 10px #f00;
  }
}

div {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulseBorder;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #f00
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the below to handle situations where the border color might be different for other elements.

This allows the use of one keyframe on multiple elements with different color borders. All you need to do is edit the rgba to be the color of the background.

```css
@keyframes border-pulse {
    50% {
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
}

#first {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid cyan;
    animation: border-pulse 2s infinite;
}

#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    animation: border-pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```